# Returning lambda with function vs with macro in common lisp

Tags: lambda, macros, common-lisp

What is the difference between using a macro and a function to return a lambda in common lisp?

```lisp
(defun f ()
  (lambda () (format t "hello world")))

(defmacro m ()
  (lambda () (format t "hello world")))

; is (f) equal to (m) ?
```

do they return the exact same thing?

And what if the returned lambda forms were quoted? (`'(lambda ...)`)

I'm asking this because in chapter 3 of Practical Common Lisp there is a macro (`where`) that returns a (back)quoted lambda, and I don't get why it could not be just a simple function that returns the same lambda.

Comment: In Chapter 3 of PCL, the `where` macro needs to be a macro because it splices code, namely `(and ,@(...))`. Previously in the chapter there was a `where` function, but it later went turned into a macro in section "Removing Duplication and Winning Big" (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html)

Comment: I see. Wouldn't it be possible to use backticks `\`` and splicing macros `,@` in a function?

Comment: Backticks and splice are not exclusive to macros, but as soon as you use a backtick, it is as-if you quoted the lambda form: the resulting value is an expression, not a function object. You need to `(coerce form 'function)` or `(eval form)`, or `(compile nil form)` to turn that into a function object.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same.

**Literal Functions in code vs. compiling a file**

For example see this file `example.lisp`:

```
(defmacro fm ()
  (lambda () (print "hi")))

(defun foo ()
  (fm))
```

Now compile the file with `(compile-file "example.lisp")`.

Chances are high that it will not work. SBCL says:

```
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (FM)
; ==>
;   #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA () :IN FM) {226680AB}>
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   Objects of type FUNCTION can't be dumped into fasl files.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
```

Why is that?

Your function `f` returns a function at runtime.

Your macro `m` returns a function at macro expansion time. That means a literal object will be included in the code. Literal functions usually can't be dumped by the file compiler.

**Next Example: function and two macros**

```
(defun f ()
  (lambda () (format t "hello world")))

(defmacro m0 ()
  (lambda () (format t "hello world")))

(defmacro m1 ()
  `(lambda () (format t "hello world")))

(defun foo ()
  (list
    (f)         ; returns a function at runtime

    (m0)        ; a literal function, created at macro expansion time
                ;   thus can't be dumped by a file compiler

    (m1)        ; a function form, (function (lambda () ...))
  ))
```

**Examples in REPL, with variables**

Now let's look with variables:

```
(defun f (a)
  (lambda (b) (list a b)))   ; A is a lexical reference to above A

(defmacro m0 (a)
  (lambda (b) (list a b)))   ; A is a lexical reference to above A (!)

(defmacro m1 (a)             ; A is unused
  `(lambda (b) (list a b)))  ; A is not a reference to above A (!)
```

now at the REPL:

```
* (defun foo (c)
    (list

     (ignore-errors (funcall (f  c) 2))
     (ignore-errors (funcall (m0 c) 2))
     (ignore-errors (funcall (m1 c) 2))

    ))
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (M1 C)
; --> LAMBDA FUNCTION 
; ==>
;   (LIST A B)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::A
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     A
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

* (foo 3)
((3 2)    ; <- runtime values
 (C 2)    ; <- C is source code
 NIL)     ; <- error, since A is undefined
```

Comment: It took me some time to understand everything. The answer seems to be: "`f` returns a function at runtime. `m` returns a function at macro expansion time. That means a literal object will be included in the code."
Further questions: 
1. if I use `(f)` and `(m)` in the REPL I won't see a difference, because in the REPL macro time and runtime happen one after the other, thus giving the same output (a function object)?
2. function form == expression that defines a function? And function literal == function object?
3. why do I need to use `funcall` to call the output of `f`, `m0`, `m1`?